# Should I agitate my beer [rock the carboy] while it's fermenting?

Tags: fermentation

Just wondering if I should agitate the carboy during fermentation/towards the end when it starts to slow?

Answer (score 1):

You can if you want.  I find it to be helpful sometimes in knocking the krausen back down so the yeast will settle out sooner.

Also, I sometimes swirl the fermenter gently to blend some yeast back into suspension on purpose to ensure full attenuation for yeasts that flocculate too quickly.

Use your best judgment.  If you think you should, I say go ahead and do it.  Just be gentle so that you aren't adding a lot of oxygen back in, as that could lead to faster staling.

Comment: Where is the oxygen coming from?

Comment: Good point.  Potential for air suckback through the airlock based on pressure differentials... assuming an airlock is installed.  If no airlock, well then there is your air source obviously.

Comment: OK just asking for clarity of others.  Usually when I shake a carboy/fermentor that has undergone some fermentation the airlock bubbles OUT due to knocking CO2 out of solution.  But I could see if fermentation was weak and the air in the headspace hadn't been displaced then maybe this would be an issue.  I think we agree in general agitation of a fermentor isn't necessary if all things are going well.